# return in a for loop C

Tags: c, function, for-loop, return

In the following code, would anything be returned?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int try_this (int in);

int main (void)
{
    try_this (5);
}

int try_this (int in)
{
    int i = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < in; i = i + 2) {
        return i;
    }

    return i;
}
```

Since there's a return in the for loop, would the code just return nothing since there's nothing after the function is called? Or would i be returned as a number, like 1(because of the declaration in try_this) or 6(because of the loop)? 
Thank you!!:)

Comment: Umm... The function is named `try_this`. I think you should just do that.

Comment: Every time `0` is returned

Comment: As soon as you reach your first `return` the function returns the value specified and the function stack is destroyed (released back to the system). ...And your compiler should be screaming at you that `function main is type int` and therefore should return a value (e.g. `return try_this(5);`). Always compile with at minimum `-Wall -Wextra` in your compile string and do not accept code until it compiles without any warnings.

Comment: It will return 0, but you are not using the returned value in main.

Comment: The initial condition of the `for` loop sets `i` to be `0`.  The first iteration, with `i` equal to `0`, will hit `return i`.   So the function will always return `0`.

Answer (score 4):

When the first `return` statement is encountered, the function will return. It's easy to see that the function will start the loop and while `i=0` it will `return i`. So each time you call try_this you'll get `0`

Also, `return 0;` from main...

Comment: You can wrap inline code in your paragraph above in *backticks* (e.g. `'\`'`) to format as code. It helps with the readability of your answer and shows a bit of additional effort.

Comment: No big deal, I fixed it for you. It must be a bear to format on those darn mobile keyboards...

Comment: BTW: If control reaches the end of the main function, return 0; is executed.

Answer (score 2):

When you enter the `for` loop for the first time, `i` is 0 and less than the `5`. Then it execute the statement `return i;` in for loop, which will finish executing the `try_this()` funciton.

Answer (score 0):

What you are basically asking is that if the function will return something even though there is no code after the function call.

The answer is yes, it will return. It doesn't matter if there is code later or not. The function will return (in this case 0) It's just that there's nobody to catch it.

Answer (score 0):

The function `try_this()` always returns `0`:

- `i` is initially set to `1`
- then `i` is set to `0` in the initial clause of the `for` statement
- if `i < in`, the loop body is executed and the value of `i` is returned, namely `0`.
- otherwise the loop is skipped and the next statement is `return i;` so `0` is returned too.

Regarding the `main` function: it ignores the return value of `try_this(5)` and reaches the end of its body without a `return` statement. This is bad style and would trigger undefined behavior for any other function, but since C99 the behavior is defined as a special case for the `main` function and the value `0` is returned to the startup code, which exits back to the system with a termination status of `0`, which means successful execution.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to store the value of 'I' i would recommend you to use "while loop"

```
int i = 0;
while(i < in)
{
 i++;
}
```

Comment: Um, no? `for` is still the better option here.